# Clicking button with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am currently working on a project I can select all elements barr one, and it getting really frustrating the code is as follows

```
<a class="btn btn-default button button-medium" href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=order" title="Proceed to checkout" rel="nofollow">
                        <span>
                            Proceed to checkout<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
```

I have tried xpath, css, linktext, title and other methods but no luck, any help would be really appreaced

example of xpath I have used

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//div[@id='layer_cart']//a[@title='Proceed to checkout']/span")).click();
```

example of css I have used

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[title='Proceed to checkout'] > span")).click();
```

Comment: Please post the error stack?

Comment: Another srange thing no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `click()` on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-default.button.button-medium[title='Proceed to checkout'] > span")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium' and @title='Proceed to checkout']/span")).click();
  ```

---

Ideally to `click()` on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.btn.btn-default.button.button-medium[title='Proceed to checkout'] > span"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium' and @title='Proceed to checkout']/span"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use icon on your button CSS:

`.icon-chevron-right right`

or xpath:

`//i[@class='icon-chevron-right right']`

Comment: Just tried this and its not working either, so strange